# Cloth vibrating with object collision turned on?

Tags: physics, collision

On the character rig I'm creating for an animation, I have a cape, which is a piece of cloth which is solidified to give it thickness. However, I want it to collide with the torso, head, and arms of the character. As soon as I turn object collision on, though, the cloth begins to vibrate, looking unrealistic and unusable.

There was someone else with a similar problem to mine, but nobody had solved it, so I'm asking again.

Here are a couple images, and the blend file is also attached.

[image]

First, above ^ is the rig, which shows the character, the cape / cloth deforming (vibrating) weirdly. You ought to be able to tell what the arms, torso, and head of the rig are.

[image]

Second is the settings for the cloth (I think that's all of them).

Also, **[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gad6sbgeiyfz7c/Characters.blend?dl=0)** is the blend file.

I hope this has been written clear enough, as I tend to ramble a bit.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I've had to get into soft cloth for another query in BSE and encountered this problem.  My solution was to 'freeze' the cloth physics, duplicate the cloth, remove the duplicate's physics and animation, and swap the original with that.  It's not a perfect solution but it's a lot better than watching it wriggling constantly. :)  Wait for someone to come up with a settings or driver answer.  If none, leave a comment and I'll pass on the procedure.

Comment: So, a few things. What do you mean by 'freeze'? Also, by doing that, I assume it won't be animated (which is kind of the point). Anyway, I'll have a go at this :).

Comment: Also, one fix I found (that didn't really go the way I wanted) was to increase the mass of the object. And once it got to around 0.6kg (which is too much for a cape, I think), it stopped vibrating, but acted like a REALLY heavy bit of cloth, not exactly what I wanted. Also I think I may have just possibly put that amount in the .blend file? If so, just change it to 0.01kg.

Comment: Freezing any constraint is to, as you mentioned, effectively remove the very engine you're needing to use.  If more physics are required. the engine needs to be used again.  It's a crude workaround but I use it constantly when objects have to be disconnected from constraints because of hang-over issues, or swapping parents, paths etc.. Animation and shapekeys are returned cleanly.